# How to Use a ResourceDictionary to Manage Localizable String Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I read this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613547(v=vs.110).aspx) which describes how to localize a resource dictionary, I followed it and used locbaml tool to localize the application, but can't find resource dictionary keys generated in csv file. I tried to make 3 resource files (StringResources.xaml, StringResources.en-US.xaml, StringResources.ar-SA.xaml) and translated strings and rebuild the project, but the strings never come localized.

Solution Explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer]

App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/lang/StringResources.xaml"/>
```

Usage:

```
private string GetString(string s)
{
    try
    {
        object locals = TryFindResource(s);
        return locals == null ? s : locals.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change the threadlocale?
As a side note, I LOVE ResXManager to manage localizations: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68

Comment: yes,
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        }

Comment: What happens when you use the default resource manager? Like this: Properties.Resources.StringResources.YourProperty; You probably have to place your resx files in the default resource folder.

Comment: @ChristianSauer whenever I try to use resx resources and named the local one "strings.ar-SA.resx" the application give an exception "cannot locate resource app.xaml". The strange thing is when I deleted whole resx files, the application still give this exception, so I'm to restore the previous working solution!

Comment: The local one needs no language extension, only the "deviant", e.g. english ones need one.
E.g.: you are in ar-SA, so your resource is named "StringResources", your translation into english is called StringResources.en-US.resx

Comment: solution neutral language is set to English, I set it explicitly inside solution file PropertGroup "<UICulture>en-US</UICulture>", so I tested to add 2 resx files (stringsresx.resx, and stringsresx.ar-SA.resx, the same exception occured "Cannot locate resource 'homepage.xaml'". homepage.xaml exists and works before making this change.

Comment: take a look at:
http://i.imgur.com/JlcI45x.jpg